# Cannot compute probabilities in SVM?

Tags: r

Using svm from e1071 in R:
I have the following code:

```
svm1<-svm(srv~., data=TrainSet,methof='C-classification',probability=TRUE)
pred.svm1<-predict(svm1,data=Test,probability=TRUE)
```

when esmining pred.svm1 I dont see the probabilities only classifications
Specifically:

```
attr(pred.svm1,"probability")

NULL
```

No sure what to do, anyway I googled around, other people had similar problems but their solutions did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

The correct name for the attribute is `probabilities` (note the plural)

hence

```
attr(pred.svm1,"probabilities")
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks I changed the code #SVM
svm1<-svm(srv~., data=TrainSet,type='C',probability=TRUE)
pred.svm1<-predict(svm1,data=Test,probability=TRUE) and then I typedattr(pred.svm1,"probabilities")
and Got NULL again...Any ideas

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit late for the OP now, but to get predictions on a test dataset, you use

```
pred.svm1 <- predict(svm1, newdata=Test, ...)
```

not

```
pred.svm1 <- predict(svm1, data=Test, ...)
```

The argument to pass a dataset to the `predict` method is called `newdata`, not `data`. As written in the question, `pred.svm1` would give the predictions on the *training* dataset, ie the data used to fit the model.

Answer (score 2):

Before you plug in the values into the model, make sure the output variable in your `Train` and `Test` data frame is of type `factor`.

```
train$OutputVar <- factor(train$OutputVar)
test$OutputVar <- factor(test$OutputVar)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been successfully using `probability=TRUE` for quite a long time with a similar syntax, but your code did not work for me. When I change your second line to:

```
pred.svm1<-predict(svm1,Test,probability=TRUE)
```

it did work (I removed the `data=`). Honestly, I don't have a clue why.

BTW, you also have a type-o on your first line: `methof` should be `type`.

Comment: It worked because the standard second argument for `predict` methods is `newdata`, not `data`.